# How to get the height of html element immediately after javascript actions on DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I want to apply a final adjustment to the layout of web pages based on the height of the html element at the time when javascript actions on DOM are complete. This action has to be immediate, therefore I do not want to use `setTimeout` function. I have tried the following, but it runs too soon before other functions can complete their action on DOM:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {  
 if(document.readyState == 'complete') {  
  alert(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].offsetHeight);
 }  
};
```

The actions on DOM include hiding of certain sections of the document, thereby shortening the height of the html element. I would not like use a callback function within these javascript functions since there are several of them and this final adjustment has to be applied on all web pages.

Is there any way that this can be done with javascript alone?

Answer (score 0):

There are (were) [DOMMutationEvents](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) - slow and not widely supported. [DOM MutationObserver](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) is the new thing to play with - browser support is still low, though.

It is not possible to do this reliably (and fast) across different browsers.

---

If you're using jQuery (exclusively) for your DOM manipulation business, you could have a look at [cssHooks](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/11-jQuery-Hooks.html#css). That option fails, as soon as the DOM is modified by anything other than through jQuery, though.

Comment: Can you show how my above code would be changed in order to use the function? Thanks.